# LG IPS 224 weird color in some programs

Tags: color-profiles, lg-monitor

I bought a new monitor, the LG IPS 224, and everything seemed fine til I opened the windows picture viewer:  everything was green, it was like a green overlay. Than I got another problem when I opened Safari: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbfq4.png]
Then I had another problem in Photoshop: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQwGF.png] where the green rectangle is supposed to be white what it is when I save it and open it in picasa where I have no color problems.

The first error in the windows picture viewer I could already solve through changing the color profile to another one than the LG IPS224 profile, e.g. to sRGBIEC61966-2.1 which was recommended for problems with a samsung monitor. But it didn't solve the problem in safari and photoshop what would be most important. Even changing the color profile to Apple RGB and to Adobe RGB didn't solve the problem in Safari and Photoshop. The drivers are up to date for the monitor and I already tried to change settings on the monitor directly. On youtube is a video where the same problem is described, but no solution. and another strange thing is, on my second monitor I have the same problems, which I never had before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem by swapping the cables from my two monitors. The new monitor is now on VGA 2 and the old on VG1 and I changed the default color profile in the control panel, in color management to sRGBIEC61966-2.1 and now everything is ok even in Photoshop and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I've been taking a close look at the .ICM color profile and it's definitely broken. The "red" value is totally nuts making everything green. The 23inch monitor profile that is on the same CD isn't broken, but those are values for another monitor. If you open Photoshop having the broken profile as your default profile in windows it warns you it's broken, and doesn't warn you if you're using the 23 inch monitor profile. You can take a look inside profiles with free software like IccXml, that's what I used to compare both profiles.

```
<XYZType>
  <TagSignature>rXYZ</TagSignature>
  <XYZNumber X="-3308.52368164" Y="-1127.65075684" Z="-16148.61914063"/>
</XYZType>
<XYZType>
  <TagSignature>gXYZ</TagSignature>
  <XYZNumber X="0.41940308" Y="0.74780273" Z="0.05749512"/>
</XYZType>
<XYZType>
  <TagSignature>bXYZ</TagSignature>
  <XYZNumber X="0.15620422" Y="0.05509949" Z="0.77340698"/>
</XYZType>
```

Those negative numbers shoud be something similar to the other ones with zero point something.

I've just checked the korean website http://lgservice.co.kr (the only one where you can download driver files for this monitor including the icm file) and there's no update at the time of writing this.

Update:

The newer LG 22EA63V seems to have the exact same panel, and non broken icm files are available from the LG korean site. I've chosen that profile manually and it's OK. [Link to 22EA63V drivers](http://www.lgservice.co.kr/cs_lg/download/SoftwareDownloadDetailCmd.laf?cSeq=7404)